# Oracle - Display an incremental ID by a simple query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, analytic-functions

I have a very simple query like this:

```
SELECT Line, ID, Enum 
  FROM tab1
```

the result is something like this:

[image]

```
Line  id   enum
A     10   1
A     10   2
A     10   3
A     10   4

...
B     20   4
B     20   5
B     20   6
B     20   7
```

...

I want, for each Line/id, the anum start by 1, just like this:

```
Line  id   enum
A     10   1
A     10   2
A     10   3
A     10   4
...
B     20   1
B     20   2
B     20   3
B     20   4
...
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need an Analytic function such as [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) :

```
SELECT Line, ID, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Line ORDER BY Enum ) AS Enum
  FROM tab1
```

where that function enumerates each `Enum` value again per each `Line` group starting from the integer 1, and sorted by currently existing `Enum` value

Perhaps you need grouping by `Line` and `ID`, then use `PARTITION BY Line, ID` instead of `PARTITION BY Line`.

*Both will produce the same result in this case.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9310c99be6684ab4f7a51794bf627d1c)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!!!